# Android Studio "Variable 'example' might not have been initialized" What do do now?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

my problem is Android Studio says "Variable 'example' might not have been initialized". This applies to these two:

```
private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
```

and in line 57 the bluetoothDevice is red underlined and says "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'bluetoothDevice'"

Hope someone can help :)

Here is my BT_Classic.java :

```
    package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;



public class BT_Classic extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button pairedButton;
private Button discoveredButton;
private Button btonButton;
private Button btoffButton;
private ProgressDialog progress;
ListView listView;
private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fc5ffc49-00e3-4c8b-9cf1-6b72aad1001a");


private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


//BLUETOOTH VERBINDUNG


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLED = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE = 0;

    private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {

        public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {


            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothSocket = temp;

        }


            public void run() {
        // Cancel any discovery as it will slow down the connection
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
    /*
        manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
    */
    }

    // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt__classic);


    pairedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pairedButton);
    discoveredButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discoveredButton);
    btonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btonButton);
    btoffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoffButton);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
            // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
            ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
            t.start();
        }
    });

    //Pairing Button

    pairedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices){
                devices.add(bt.getName());
                devices.add(bt.getAddress());

            }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(BT_Classic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devices);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });








    discoveredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            }


        }
    });

    btonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_ENABLED);
        }
    });

    btoffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btAdapter.disable();
        }
    });










}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put it this way;

```
private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {

public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {



    BluetoothSocket temp = null;
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bluetoothSocket = temp;


}
```

Comment: thanks but now it says Cannot assign a value to final variable 'bluetoothSocket' aaand Modifier private is not allowed here

Comment: Remove final and private. I have edited my code. Please do not forget to delete it from BT_Classic class where you initially declared it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still having the same problem. blueooth socket is marked red and     private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice; I will update my post so you can see the full code now

Comment: Delete private final BluetoothSocket and private final BluetoothDevice anywhere you see them because I have declared and initialised them in the code above. You are getting those error because you still have them above. A final variable cannot be assigned a value again

Comment: okay okay I did that, I glad I came so far :D but now it says Class or interface expected in line 102... This is so frustrating

Comment: I think that is another issue that is different from this, kindly mark this as answered and ask a new question with the new code. We cannot see lines here. I do not know where line 102 is except you show a new code

Comment: Ill do that Thank you very much anyway, you were very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Defining final variables need either inline instantiation or instantiation in the same class's constructor. I mean following lines:

```
private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
```

these variables must be initialized in constructor of `BT_Classic`.